# cakephp paginator sort fields with i18n

Tags: php, cakephp, internationalization

I have an application done with cakephp, and I have i18n done on the databse, following the instructions on the cakephp book. The thing is that on the table at the index view, I can't sort by the fields that are translated. The field's don't actually exist on the database, so here is where I suppose the problem comes, but I can insert data on the field, so the i18n is working properly.

I've tried several ways of setting the paginator, but none work.

For example, I've tried:

```
Paginator->sort('Name','name');
Paginator->sort('Name','I18n__name');
Paginator->sort('Name','I18n__name.content');
```

As I see, on the queries, it fetches the field refering to it as I18n__name.content', so I thought this would work, but it doesn't.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found it. I think this should to work out of the box in cakephp. But until they add this, there is a way to make it work.

On the paginatro use the form:

```
Paginator->sort('Name','I18n__name.content');
```

And then, the only thing that needs to be done is add the following function in the model.

```
function hasField($fieldName) {
    if (parent::hasField($fieldName))
        return true;
    else
        switch ($fieldName) {
            case "content":
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    return false; 
}
```

And that's it, now the fields that are translated can be ordered in a paginated table.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use something like

```
echo $this->Paginator->sort('Name', __('Content', true));
```

and then let the __() function render a translated name if necessary. Or am I misunderstanding the problem?

Cheers
Arno

Comment: Using __() is for static fields, so the translations have to be in the po files. I'm using the Translate Behavior so whenever I add a new entity in the database I can provide the translations. So the translations are actually stored in the database.

Answer (score 0):

In Cake 1.3.10

Just  `$paginator->sort(__('test',true),'field_name');` will work

Translated content goes first, database field name goes is second parameter.

As defined in:
http://api.cakephp.org/class/paginator-helper#method-PaginatorHelpersort